# Values been overrided in a list

Tags: c++

I'm working in c++. I need to create and store a list of this objects(the first two are part of the third one):

```
typedef char tipo_cadena[50];

union tipo_valor {
    int c_entero;
    float c_real;
    bool c_bool;
};

struct tipo_datoTS {
    tipo_cadena nombre;
    int tipo;
    union tipo_valor valor;
};
```

The thing is that when I insert some values in my list it's overriding all of them with the last one. For example if I insert 1,2,3,4 (assuming I'm using int for the example) the list will have 4,4,4,4.

I think I'm using some pointer wrong (it's been a long time since I use c). Here is the code where I add the value:

```
union tipo_valor valor;
struct tipo_datoTS *dato;
strcpy(dato->nombre, $1);
valor.c_entero = $3;
dato->tipo = 1;
dato->valor = valor;
myList->add(dato);
```

The list code is long and I think it's right (I've used it before) so I won't post it until there's no other option to keep the question simple.

Comment: Please study and apply the concept of a [mcve].

Comment: In C++ you don't need to say `struct` when declaring variables. class and structure names automatically become type names.

Comment: What is `$1` and `$3`?

Comment: @Barmar, sorry I didn't explain it. I'm using c++ inside a Bison program. That's like a parameter. To be clear: I know their types and they are in a good use there. Also, I've deleted the 'struct', thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
struct tipo_datoTS *dato;
strcpy(dato->nombre, $1);
```

The first line makes `dato` a pointer, but doesn't assign it a value, so it doesn't point to anything. The second line tries to copy something into the `nombre` member of the object `dato` points to, but `dato` doesn't point to any object.

Comment: How do I initialize a dato object here?

Comment: @JaimeAlcántaraArnela `tipo_datoTS *dato = new tipo_datoTS;`

Comment: That was it... as easy as that... Okey, I'm a little confused with C, thanks!

Comment: @JaimeAlcántaraArnela In C it you would use `malloc(sizeof(struct tipo_datoTS))`.